# Gradle 5.0: java.lang.String cannot be cast to class groovy.lang.Closure (lombok issue)

Tags: gradle

I am encountering error during Gradle 5.0 upgrade (from 4.10.2) and have isolated the code to the following block:

```
dependencyManagement {
    dependencies {
        compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2"
        testCompileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2"
        annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2"
        testAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2"
        dependency "com.google.guava:guava:$guavaVersion"
        dependency "mysql:mysql-connector-java:$mysqlversion"
        dependency "com.google.inject:guice:${guiceVersion}"
        dependency "org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.1.1.RELEASE"
    }
    imports {
        mavenBom org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES
        mavenBom "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:${awsVersion}"
    }
}
```

Without the lombok lines, the code works with no issue.

```
dependencyManagement {
    dependencies {
        dependency "com.google.guava:guava:$guavaVersion"
        dependency "mysql:mysql-connector-java:$mysqlversion"
        dependency "com.google.inject:guice:${guiceVersion}"
        dependency "org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.1.1.RELEASE"
    }
    imports {
        mavenBom org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES
        mavenBom "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:${awsVersion}"
    }
}
```

The error is `class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class groovy.lang.Closure (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; groovy.lang.Closure is in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @675d3402)`

I am changing the way lombok is declared due to changes in Gradle 5 annotation processing.

Comment: I think you're mixing up the dependencyManagement and the actual dependencies

Answer (score 2):

In the `dependencies` block under `dependencyManagement` there should not be any concrete dependency declaration eg. `compileOnly`, `testCompileOnly` etc. Only `dependency` is allowed as it is where you define all the - well - dependencies with the proper version for later use in the sub-projects.